# variable can not fetched outside head

Tags: jquery, json

I'm kind of new to JSON and jQuery. Here what I want to do is fetching the data from JSON and display it in html table.The problem is when i write `document.write(ht);`into `head`section of the html file everything works fine. But when i write `document.write(ht);`into body of the html like this then it just show `undefined` as output.I cant figure out why  is it so.

Following is text.json file:

```
   {
     "red":"new_small.gif",
     "green":"new_small.gif"
   }
```

Following is html file:

```
     <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
     <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
     <head>
     <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
     <title>Untitled Document</title>
      <script src="jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
      <script  type="text/javascript">
        var items = [];
        var ht;
        $.getJSON('text.json', function(data) {
        ht='<table>';
        $.each(data, function(key, val) {
        ht+= '<tr><td>' + key + '</td><td><img src="' + val+ '"></td></tr>';
       });
        ht+='</table>';
      }).success(function() { alert("success"); })
        .error(function() { alert("error"); })
        .complete(function() { alert("complete"); });  
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <script> 
    document.write(ht);  
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 2):

`ht` is set asynchronously trough the callback function in your `$.getJSON` call, but your document.write is fired immediately.

Comment: Yes it will, but you really should not resort to that, just append the html to the body in your callback function :)

Comment: but i need to replace $getJSON with $.ajax to make it synchronous

Comment: you shouldn't use a syncronous request, what's the problem with appending the content from within your callback function ?

Answer (score 0):

After ht+='table>';  use this

```
  $('div/>', {
    html: ht
  }).appendTo('body');
```